# Easy text re-wrapping

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

I'm looking for a tool that allows me to easily **re-wrap text**, i.e. a tool that removes line breaks, but not empty lines, from a text selection or text field, and that works on Chrome and on Windows.

Bonus points for anything that works outside of the browser too, and that works **in-place** (i.e. that doesn't require copy-pasting the text through a separate window or using something like http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php)

Browser extensions, GreaseMonkey scripts or applications that also work on Linux and/or Mac (or even better, that are multi-platform) are all welcomed.

Here is an example of how the tool should behave. If I have the following in a text field:

```
This is a test for SuperUser.com. This is 
a test for SuperUser.com. This is
a test for
SuperUser.com. This is a test 
for SuperUser.com 

This is a test for SuperUser.com. This is 
a test for SuperUser.com. This 
is
a 
test
for SuperUser.com. This is a test for SuperUser.com
```

then, using a (e.g. keyboard) shortcut, the tool should convert it to:

> This is a test for SuperUser.com. This
>   is a test for SuperUser.com. This a
>   test for SuperUser.com. This is a test
>   for SuperUser.com
>
> This is a test for SuperUser.com. This
>   is a test for SuperUser.com. This a
>   test for SuperUser.com. This is a test
>   for SuperUser.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want that functionality within Google Chrome? (since you mention "applications")

Comment: At the very least, anything that works on Chrome on Windows would work for me. But it would be great if we could also find something that works outside the browser and that is cross-platform.

Comment: Well this may not meat your exact specifications so I'll post it as a comment. Anything that that has regular expressions would be able to do this with find replace like notepad++(http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Switch replace mode to regular expressions then replace /n with nothing.

Comment: What is the difference between a line break and a paragraph break? Is it just '<text>\n<text>' compared to '<text>\n\n<text>' ?

Comment: @Puddingfox, It probably depends of how the text is encoded and rendered (e.g. in HTML it might mean <p></p> or <br></br>), but ideally the tool should work **regardless** of how the line breaks or paragraphs are encoded (i.e. it should respect the underlying text markup language). After all, I am asking for a **WYSIWYG** (What You See Is What You Get) solution.

Comment: That answer doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Firstly, it doesn't even answer what counts as a paragraph break for plain text. Secondly, the difference between a line break and a paragraph break is a semantic distinction, which is not represented in how something looks. If you want a WYSIWYG solution, you need a WYSIWYG/"how it looks" definition of the problem.

Comment: @frabjous, As far as I can tell, the question comes with a clear WYSIWYG definition of the problem. There is not even need to define what a paragraph is to address the underlying problem, but in case it helps, there is a fairly conventional encoding system that LaTeX, MediaWiki and other document preparation systems and text mark-up languages stick to, which is: a paragraph break is represented by one or more empty lines.

Comment: I removed any references to "paragraphs" or "paragraph breaks" from the problem statement to avoid confusion.

Comment: You want a text editor tool inside your browser?

Comment: Obviously, the question, as originally stated wasn't clear enough to Puddingfox, or (s)he wouldn't have asked. Still, there's the question "what's a blank line". In LaTeX, the blank line could have any amount of whitespace on it, it doesn't need to be \n\n. My vim solution below also allows the line to have nothing but whitespace on it (tabs, spaces, etc.), also reduces multiple blank lines to one blank line, and removes the spaces and tabs from the blank line. Do you want that, or do you want them all left alone, no matter how many?

Comment: @Frabjous, I appreciate your Vim solution, and would vote for it if I had enough reputation. I'll look into it more carefully, but at the moment I need something that also works in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Not browser, not cross-platform, but might be useful for someone anyway:

TextMate for Mac OS X has the command *Edit » Unwrap Paragraph/Selection* (`Ctrl-Opt-Q`) for exactly this purpose.

---

Emacs has `M-q` for this purpose, you might have to assign a [greater width than default](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillParagraph#toc2).

---

Use the following Python script (written on OS X, but otherwise cross-platform):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

current = "\n"
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line != "\n":
        sys.stdout.write(current[:-1])
    else:
        print "\n"
    current = line
print current[:-1]
```

Invoke like this:

```
cat test.txt | ./rewrap.py
```

On Mac OS X, create a *Service* using `Automator` in *any application* that receives *text* as input and *replaces selected text*. Add a *Run Shell Script* action that passes input to `stdin` and call the Python script above. Assign a global keyboard shortcut for any application in *System Preferences » Keyboard*.

[image]

Comment: These solutions are great, Daniel, thank you!. However, I think I'm still looking for something else. 

The python idea is interesting, but I am not sure if or how I could use that as an **in-place** solution when editing a text field in my browser. Also, I use Emacs when coding, so thanks for the tip, but I need something that works on the browser.

Comment: @AmV then see my most recent edit. At least on OS X, you get the Python script in any application, thanks to Services and Automator.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. They look like a great fit for OS X, and I would vote you up if I had enough reputation to do it (I just signed up). Unfortunately I need something that works under Windows as well.

Comment: @AmV You should really include this requirement in your question. As it is, it didn't seem to matter on which system, as long as it's in all applications. Well, at least I got a global rewrap/unwrap command out of it ;)

Comment: Good point. I added the "at least in my browser (Chrome) **and** on Windows" requirement at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Clipboard Fusion by Binary Fortress Software. I have it set so when ever I copy text from certain applications (Adobe Reader), copied text is automatically stripped of line breaks. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

[(G)Vim](http://www.vim.org) can do this. E.g., put this in your .vimrc:

`vnoremap <F5> :s/\s*\n\s*\n\s*/<<mybreak>>/g<CR>gvJgv:s/<<mybreak>>/\r\r/g<CR>`

This assigns the key <kbd>F5</kbd> (you can use whatever you want instead; with vim you can customize all the keymappings however you want) to do all the following: while in "visual mode" (i.e., when a block of text is selected), replace all linebreaks in the selected text followed by a line with nothing but whitespace followed by another linebreak with the placeholder `<<mybreak>>`, rehighlight the same portion and join all the lines, reducing all whitespace between lines to a single space,, rehighlight the same portion and replace the placeholder `<<mybreak>>` with two newlines to restore the paragraph breaks.

Of course, you don't need to remember anything but <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Actually, there's probably a simpler way to do this in vim. My vim skills are nothing compared to some; this is just how it occurred to me to do it.

Can you use it in a browser: perhaps not directly, but with Firefox plugins such as [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/) or [pentadactyl](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/) allow you to edit all webfields in vim (or any other text editor of your chosing), so then you'd be able to use it there too.

Answer (score 1):

using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12991&p=66653#p66653) (open-source):

This code will allow you to copy to the clipboard (using CTRL+ALT+C *) and unwrap it (ready to be past). Like a normal copy past, and it will keep empty lines between paragraphs.

```
!^+c::                 ;copy + unwrap but keep the empty lines
clipboard =
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{ESC}
ClipWait
NewStr := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "([^\r\n])\R([^\r\n])", "$1$2")
clipboard = %NewStr%
ClipWait
return
```

- you can change your shortcut by any key just by changing the first line.