# Is there a clipboard manager that can paste neglecting the format?

Tags: clipboard, text-formatting

I know there are bunch of clipboard managers. But I am looking for a feature in them. I want to paste (by using a different shortcut) without the formats. Because when **I want to get rid of the format** I always paste the text to notepad and then cut it again and use it in another place...

Comment: Press `Cmd-Opt-Shift-V` in pretty much any OS X application for *Paste and Match Style*, i.e. paste without keeping formatting.

Comment: Using autohotkey, you could do that and even unwrap the the text. http://superuser.com/questions/231832/easy-text-re-wrapping/1025933#1025933

Answer (score 2):

[Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) will do this for you. The Ctrl+` hotkey will bring up the list of recently copied items, and Shift-Enter will past the selected item without any formatting.

There's also a hotkey option to do a text-only paste of whatever you've copied most recently. It's set to None by default, you can rebind it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one, and really like it:

http://stevemiller.net/puretext/

It creates a hot-key that pastes without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In many Microsoft applications you can use CTRL + ALT + v to open the "paste special" windows which allows you to choose to paste without formatting.